# How to create a custom collator?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, locale, collation

I am using the following code to use as function to sort a list of strings:

```
bool stringLessThan(const string& str1, const string& str2) 
{
   const collate<char>& col = use_facet<collate<char> >(locale()); // Use the global locale

   string s1(str1);
   string s2(str2);

   transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(), ::tolower);
   transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), ::tolower);
   const char* pb1 = s1.data();
   const char* pb2 = s2.data();
   return (col.compare(pb1, pb1 + s1.size(), pb2, pb2 + s2.size()) < 0);
}
```

I am setting the global locale as:

```
locale::global(locale("pt_BR.UTF-8"));
```

If I use the `en_EN.UTF-8` locale, the words with accent in my language (portuguese-Brazil) will be in different order that I want. So I use `pt_BR.UTF-8`. But, the string "as" is before "a", and I want "a" and then "as".

The reason is that collator ignores the spaces, and strings like:

```
a pencil
an apple
```

will be considered as:

```
apencil
anapple
```

and if sorted, will appear in this order:

```
an apple
a pencil
```

but I want:

```
a pencil
an apple
```

I made this with Java and the solution was create a custom collator. But in c++ how can I handle with it?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you now, but I do have a tip: you should not create temporary strings inside your comparison function if you care at all about performance.  Construction and copying of these strings will be quite inefficient, and if you are using this comparison function e.g. for a std::map, the comparator will be called many times, compounding the inefficiency.

Comment: Ok, I need the `const`. What can I do instead ?

Comment: On my machine `en_US.utf8` and `pt_BR.utf8` seem to do exactly the same thing (and they ignore the case so your tolower transformation is redundant).

Comment: @n.m. I agree that the transformation is redundant. But `en_US.UTF-8` and `pt_BR.UTF-8` is different when use accent. Try sort this: `Terror`, `Suspense` and `Épico`. Will be different.

Comment: They work identically for me (Épico, Suspense, Terror). I use `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::locale("en_US.utf8"));` and `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::locale("pt_BR.utf8"));`. They are different from say `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::locale("C"));` What is the order on your machine?

Comment: For `pt_BR.UTF-8`: `Épico`, `Suspense` and `Terror`. For `en_US.UTF-8`: `Suspense`, `Terror` and `Épico`. I am passing the function `stringLessThan` to `sort` as parameter.

Comment: Your en_US.UTF-8 seems broken. What the program [on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/collate) prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your own collator class or comparison function.  While in Java the more idiomatic approach might be to do this through extension, in c++ and for your case I'd recommend using composition.

This simply means that your custom collator class would have a collator member that it would use to help it perform collation, as opposed to deriving from the `collate` class.

As for your rules for comparison, it seems that you will need to explicitly implement your own logic. If you don't want spaces to be ignored, perhaps you should tokenize your strings.